# initWithArray seems to give a reference to source array rather then a new array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my code I use initWithArray like so :

```
vendorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:resultsCore.availableVendors];
```

But changes I make to the vendorArray also seem to be made to restultsCore.availableVendors.

This was not what I had desired.

I want populate vendorArray with restultsCore.availableVendors but then leave it untouched by the changes I make to vendorArray.

Is there away to get this functionality without using an for and if statements to copy the data object by object into vendorArray from restultsCore.availableVendors ?

Many Thanks

-Code

*EDIT* Below is my edit.

Vendors is an object i made

```
@interface Vendor : NSObject 
{
NSString        *vendorID;
NSMutableArray  *availableCars; 
BOOL            atAirport;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *vendorID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *availableCars;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL atAirport;

- (id)initFromVehVendorAvailsDictionary:(NSDictionary *)vehVendorAvails;

@end
```

As you can see it has an array.

This array is another object I made called Car.

```
@interface Car : NSObject
```

{
    NSMutableArray  *vehicleCharges; // These are extras like breakdown assist etc
    NSString    *rateQualifier;
    BOOL        needCCInfo;
    NSMutableArray  *fees; // This array contains 3 dictionarys
    NSMutableArray  *pricedCoverages;
   }

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *vehicleCharges;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *rateQualifier;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL needCCInfo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *fees;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pricedCoverages;

- (id) initFromVehicleDictionary:(NSDictionary *)vehicleDictionary;
```

@end

Car also has 3 arrays of my other objects. Its all very object oriented -.-

I've been reading up on NSCopying and saw a tutorial. But I still feel really lost as what to do here.

Do I need to implement the NSCopying protocol for my Vendors class, Car class and the other 3 classes that are contained in the arrays by car.

Vendors is the object contained in the array i want to copy. So is this the only class i need to implement the NSCopying tutorial for?

Many thanks, sorry for the long question
-Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vendorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:resultsCore.availableVendors copyItems:YES];
```

Don't forget to implement the NSCopying protocol in the classes for the objects to be copied.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I added an edit relating to the NSCopying protocol.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html

It will actually generate the code for you (no I am not affiliated with the author :))